# Adding a column to a dataframe through a mapping between 2 dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I asked something similar yesterday but I had to rephrase the question and change the dataframes that I'm using. So here is my question again:
I have a dataframe called df_location. In this dataframe I have duplicated ids because each id has a timestamp.

```
location = {'location_id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
            'temperature_value':[20,21,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37],
            'humidity_value':[60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76]}
df_location = pd.DataFrame(location)
```

I have another dataframe called df_islands:

```
islands = {'island_id':[10,20,30,40,50,60],
             'list_of_locations':[[1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8],[9],[10]]}
df_islands = pd.DataFrame(islands)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to map the values of list_of_locations to the location_id. If the values are the same , then the island_id for this location should be appended to a new column in df_location.
(Note that: I don't want to remove any duplicated Id, I need to keep them as they are)

Resulting dataframe:

```
final_dataframe = {'location_id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                'temperature_value': [20,21,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37],
                'humidity_value':[60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76],
                'island_id':[10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20,20,30,30,40,40,40,50,60]}
df_final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(final_dataframe)
```

This is just a sample from the dataframe that I have. What I have is dataframe of 13,000,0000 rows and 4 columns. How can this be achieved in an efficient way ? Is there a pythonic way to do it ?I tried using for loops but it takes too long and still it didn't work. I would really appreciate it if someone can give me a solution to this problem.

Comment: df_location can't be created from this data: ValueError: arrays must all be same length. Could you please verify that the data you provide is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
island_lookup = df_islands.explode("list_of_locations").rename(columns = {"list_of_locations": "location"})
pd.merge(df_location, island_lookup, left_on="location_id", right_on="location").drop("location", axis=1)
```

The output is:

```
   location_id  temperature_value  humidity_value  island_id
0            1                 20              60         10
1            1                 21              61         10
2            1                 22              62         10
3            1                 23              63         10
4            2                 24              64         20
5            2                 25              65         20
6            2                 27              66         20
7            3                 28              67         20
8            3                 29              68         20
9            3                 30              69         20
10           4                 31              63         30
11           5                 32              64         30
12           6                 33              65         40
13           7                 34              66         40
14           8                 35              67         40
15           9                 36              68         50
16          10                 37              69         60
```

If some of the locations don't have a matching `island_id`, but you'd still like to see them in the results (with `island_id` NaN), use `how="left"` in the merge statement, as in:

```
island_lookup = df_islands.explode("list_of_locations").rename(columns = {"list_of_locations": "location"})
pd.merge(df_location, island_lookup, 
         left_on="location_id", 
         right_on="location", 
         how = "left").drop("location", axis=1)
```

The result would be (note location-id 12 on row 3):

```
   location_id  temperature_value  humidity_value  island_id
0            1                 20              60       10.0
1            1                 21              61       10.0
2            1                 22              62       10.0
3           12                 23              63        NaN
4            2                 24              64       20.0
5            2                 25              65       20.0
6            2                 27              66       20.0
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Perfectly works. However, when I was checking the total number of rows in df_location which has 13884426 rows it is much greater than that of the merged dataframe which has 13795945 rows. I found that len(location_id)=304 and len(location)=300 so 4 IDs are missing which are (323,324,164,166). How is it possible to keep those IDs in the merged dataframe and setting the value of their island_id as NAN ?

Comment: Edited my answer to solve this case. If it answers your question, it would be great if you could accept it as an answer for future generations.